# Why has my chrome inspector toolbar moved to the top? And how to put it back?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

The toolbar of chrome's inspector (with the icons to toggle console, icon to see number of js errors/warnings, and toggle positioning of inspector) randomly repositioned itself to the top right of the inspector window, and I can't figure out how to put it back to the bottom of the window. Here's an image :

[image]

Any help is how to reposition it back to the bottom would be so greatly appreciated! The new positioning is driving me insane.

Comment: Downgrade chrome to a previous version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't put it back. This is the new layout is in v32, you updated Chrome recently to get this change.